# How to use set() based on one of the lists in a zipped list

Tags: python, set, zip

I am creating my own dictionary and trying to remove any duplicated words. I have a text file with each line having the format: word - definition . I imported the text file into python and created two list; one of all the words and one of all the definitions. I zipped the two lists together which gave a list of tuples where each element of the list is a tuple of (word, definition). I am trying to use set() on the zipped list based on only the word in order to remove duplicated words even if the definitions are different strings.

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow! Unfortunately your actual question isn't clear as to what you require help on. Please provide a [mcve] including sample input, sample output, and code for what you've tried so far. Though, you may be overthinking it if I understand the problem. If you add the data to a dict, the duplicate keys will be overwritten anyway, since dict keys must be unique

Comment: @Matthew I think you might be taking the wrong approach here. There's a datatype actually called a dictionary, which has a set of unique keys each associated with a value. In this case your dictionary words, can have values of definitions. https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries might be a good place to get started

Comment: If you're creating a dictionary, you should use a `dict`. Or, even better, use a `defaultdict(list)`, so that you end up with a list of definitions for each word.

Answer (score 0):

Use a dictionary a set isn
t the correct container for this *(FYI it will retain the last duplicate elements unless you reverse the list)*

```
zipped_list = [('apple', 'a red fruit'), ('apple', 'delicious'), ('banana', 'a yellow fruit')]

print(dict(zipped_list))
print(dict(reversed(zipped_list)))
```

---

```
{'apple': 'delicious', 'banana': 'a yellow fruit'}
{'banana': 'a yellow fruit', 'apple': 'a red fruit'}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you really need set for some reasons as output result:

```
dct = {k: v for k,v in [('word', 'meaning'), ('another_word', 'another_meaning'), ('word', 'different meaning')]}
result = set((k,v) for k,v in dct.items())
```